# how to inject dependencies into an access controller?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I am altering an existing route and adding a custom access. The custom access is a method that I want to have it in it's own access controller:

```
  /**
   * Alters existing routes.
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteBuildEvent $event) {
    $collection = $event->getRouteCollection();

    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.clone_form')) {
      // Add custom access
      $route->setRequirement('_custom_access', '\Drupal\eclone_extras\Controller\EcloneExtrasAccessController::access');
    }
  }
```

Then in my access controller I have:

```
namespace Drupal\eclone_extras\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class EcloneExtrasAccessController extends ControllerBase{

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The entity type ID.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $entityTypeId;

  /**
   * Constructs a new ContentEntityCloneBase.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   * @param string $entity_type_id
   *   The entity type ID.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, $entity_type_id) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->entityTypeId = $entity_type_id;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function createInstance(ContainerInterface $container, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $entity_type->id()
    );
  }
  /**
   * Custom access checker for the create lock requirements route.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\content_lock\Routing\ContentLockRoutes::routes()
   */
  public function access() {
    // do access stuff
    return TRUE;
  }

}
```

But I keep getting the following errors:

```
0 passed in /var/www/drupal8/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/ControllerBase.php on line 118 and exactly 2 expected in Drupal\eclone_extras\Controller\EcloneExtrasAccessController->__construct() (line 36 of modules/custom/eclone_extras/src/Controller/EcloneExtrasAccessController.php).
```

Comment: You need your class to extend Controllerbase or implement ContainerInjectionInterface yourself, otherwise the class resolver can't provide you with the container to get the injected services from.

Comment: @4K4 sorry, this was with `extend ControllerBase` as you can tell from the error.  I updated the code.

Comment: OK, then it's createInstance(), which should be named create() to override the method in ControllerBase.

Comment: I think `access()` should return `Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult`.  For example, `Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::allowed()`.

Comment: 4k4 is correct, createInstance should be create(), overriding ControllerBase::create https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/function/ControllerBase%3A%3Acreate/8.5.x

Comment: Can this be done using a service instead? Dependencies can then be added to `eclone_extras.services.yml` and passed through that way. This seems to be the way it's going elsewhere in Drupal.

Comment: Services do not have a create() method to override. Controllers are not a service, and they also have a create() method, so personally I don't think declaring it as a service is the correct way to go, as it could cause confusion if the controller is ever extended and the developer tries to override a create() method that has been bypassed by declaring the Controller a service.

Comment: A Custom Access class doesn't have to be a controller, in fact it's simpler if they aren't. Typically it would reside under src/Access instead, I've updated my answer.  There is no need for a create method. There are different ways to override an access check on a route rather than extending it. I'd need a use case to provide an example. See also:  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2266817

Comment: Access handlers don't need to be controllers, and in the example given by the OP, there is no reason for it to be. But neither is there any reason for there to be any dependency injection, so I'm thinking we haven't been shown the full code. Custom access callbacks can be added to controllers however, and defined as such in the .routing.yml file, in which case having the access callback in the class that extends ControllerBase would make sense, and would not be a service, since it is extending ControllerBase.

Comment: Yes, I was answering the specific question regarding "dependency injection". I seem to recall reading it might be possible to pass extra parameters to the access callback but it's not something I've come across yet.

Comment: I agree we seem to be missing something in the example code provided.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using services. Here's an example which injects the entity type manager interface.

eclone_extras.services.yml:

```
services:
  eclone_extras.access:
    class: Drupal\eclone_extras\Access\EcloneExtrasAccess
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager']
```

Route subscriber:

```
 /**
   * Alters existing routes.
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteBuildEvent $event) {
    $collection = $event->getRouteCollection();

    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.clone_form')) {
      // Add custom access
      $route->setRequirement('_custom_access', 'eclone_extras.access::access');
    }
  }
```

Access class:

```
namespace Drupal\eclone_extras\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;

class EcloneExtrasAccess {

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * Constructs a new ContentEntityCloneBase.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   * @param string $entity_type_id
   *   The entity type ID.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * Custom access checker for the create lock requirements route.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\content_lock\Routing\ContentLockRoutes::routes()
   */
  public function access() {
    // do access stuff
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }

}
```

The access callback gets some parameters as well, such as Account and possibly request.

Refs:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes

Comment: I couldn't get this to work until I changed the second argument of `$route->setRequirement()` to the service name: `eclone_extras.access` rather than the class name `\Drupal\eclone_extras\Controller\EcloneExtrasAccessController`.  It says that at the bottom of the documentation page here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/advanced-route-access-checking and this answer is correct as well, but I just wanted to emphasize it for others.